# Wrong Answer in Online Judge with Correct Outpout

Tags: python-3.x

so I am trying to solve the next problem from UVa Online Judge: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1415

I've written a program in Python3. My problem is that I keep getting "Wrong Answer" when I submit my program. I have checked it a million times with different inputs, including the one from uDebug. I get the exact same output as expected in every case. It is very frustrating because I think it may be a format error, since I know the judge is very picky. However, I can't find the problem with my code. I would appreciate if someone could help. My code:

```
import math

#Binary_search (recursive)

def binary_search(the_array, the_key, imin, imax):
    if (imax < imin):
        return None
    else:
        imid = imin + ((imax - imin) / 2)
        imid = math.floor(imid)
        if the_array[imid] > the_key:
            return binary_search(the_array, the_key, imin, imid-1)
        elif the_array[imid] < the_key:
            return binary_search(the_array, the_key, imid+1, imax)
        else:
            return imid


#problem solution

case = 1

while True:

    canicas = [ ]
    queries = [ ]

    N, Q = input().split(' ')

    N = int(N)
    Q= int(Q)

    if(N == 0 and Q == 0):
        break
    else:
        for i in range(N):
            x = int(input())
            canicas.append(x)
        for j in range(Q):
            x = int(input())
            queries.append(x)

        canicas.sort()

        print ("CASE# %d:" % case)

        for q in queries:

            pos = binary_search(canicas, q, 0, N-1)

            if(pos != None):
                if(pos == 0):
                    print("%d found at 1" % q)
                    break
                if(canicas[pos-1] == q):
                    print("%d found at %d" % (q, pos))
                else:
                    print("%d found at %d" % (q, pos+1))
            else:
                print("%d not found" % q)

    case += 1
```